# Nokogiri get element if type is in brackets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

I have a content like this:

```
[caption id=\"attachment_3182\" align=\"aligncenter\" width=\"800\" caption=\"blah blah\"]<img class=\"size-full wp-image-3182\" title=\"blah\" src=\"http://www.test.com/blah.jpg\" alt=\"\" width=\"800\" height=\"533\" />[/caption]
<div>other code here</div>
```

I want to get all `caption` elements from it, so I'm trying to do something like this:

`doc.css("[caption]")` and `doc.xpath('.//[caption]')`

but have had no success.

Comment: XML and HTML don’t use `[]` for elements, they use `<>`. If this is what your file looks like you’ll need to use something other than an XML parser to extract the data you want.

Comment: this is the blog post exported from wordpress so in this case the caption is the wordpress element the rest is the standard html code

Comment: In the sample you have given there are __no__ `caption` elements (in the XML or HTML sense), there is just some text that says `caption` inside some square brackets. You will have to find some other way to parse it and extract the data you need.

Comment: got it, transformed it with gsub to <caption> tag

Comment: Sometimes we have to do fixups before passing the content to the parser. The parser shouldn't be lenient when seeing what should be XML but isn't, because the XML spec requires rigid conformity, otherwise it's not XML. HTML, while similar to XML, isn't well-formed most of the time, so the parse does fixups on it before parsing. In both HTML and XML though, tags are expected to start with `<` and end with `>` so anything not so enclosed isn't a tag.

Comment: For your future self: `'.//[caption]'` isn't a good selector to use. `//` means start at the top of the DOM, which conflicts with `.`. Either `./` or `//` would be more sensible.

Answer (score 0):

Try `doc.css("[caption]").attr("caption")`

Comment: doc.css("[caption]") is an empty array and the caption is not an attribute it's something like tag

Answer (score 0):

I transformed `[caption]` to a `<caption>` tag. In my case it was:

```
text.gsub!("[caption", "<caption").gsub!('"]', '">').gsub!("[/caption]", "</caption>")
```

after that I was able to get the `<caption.` tag with Nokogiri.